# Is there anyway I can modify expiration time of get-login-password token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ecr

I am able to get token to access aws ecr using `get-login-password`. Default authorization token is valid for 12 hours. Is there anyway I can modify default value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the latest [AWS CLI Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html)

> The authorization token is valid for 12 hours.

And does not mention any way to change this. It would be safe to assume that there is no way to change the expiration time as of now.

Comment: Link for the aws v2: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html (still 12 hours).